# How to strip out multiple effects from a metric?

Tags: effects

When users report "Support Contacts" metric in the monthly meetings, sometimes it is decreasing and that can be caused by our operations like agent training (good thing), and sometimes it is decreasing and that can be caused by other factors like errors in the product (bad thing). The message that this metric is conveying is not clear and we cannot derive conclusions. 
I want to give users the ability to strip out all these other factors and report on the net support contacts that is pure and does not include other effects. 
How can I do that, any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @Tarek, is the metric a calculated value or is it a raw (base) value?

Comment: It is a raw base value. Support Contacts is the number of contacts we get to the call center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used SAS UCM procedure as I can strip out seasonality, irregularity, and factors effects and be left with S_Level variable which is what is left after removing the above mentioned effects.